# Issue when using the following namespace Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, .net, azure, active-directory, identity-management

I am getting the following error when trying to load the following namespace

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
```

> Error - The type or namespace IdentityModel does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.

Running on .NET Framework 4.6.

Package for `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` v3.19.2

Comment: Your question is confusing; one doesn't load a namespace.   Have you included the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory NuGet package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/). Did you read the note about using Microsoft.Identity.Client instead. Please include a description of your environment (.NET version, related packages include (and whether you are using packages.config or not))

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the `Microsoft.Identity.Client`  package version `4.47.2` in Visual studio 2019 using the nuget package manager under tools shown below and `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` is [deprecated](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/):

[image]

Install the package and check in the console output whether it is installed successfully or not as shown below:

[image]

Now, we can use that package in the code.